# django "type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'DoesNotExist' "

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django restapi framework and trying to do crud , I completed with insert ,update ,select operations but cant delete record. I'm little stuck with this ponit if anyone can tell which direction I should go to fix this I'ill be really glad ty.

**urls.py** I try both url and path version

```
   path('user/profile/add', views.AddProfile.as_view(), name='user_profile_add'),   
     # path('user/profile/delete/<int:id>', views.DeleteProfile.as_view(), name='user_profile_delete'), 
    url(r'^user/profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.DeleteProfile.as_view(), name='user_profile_add'),
```

**views.py**

```
class DeleteProfile(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

     def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        userprofile = self.get_object_or_404(id=pk)
        userprofile.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'userid', 'accounttype')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, render_to_response 
from .models import UserProfile 
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated 
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.views import APIView 
from rest_framework import serializers 
from rest_framework import status

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='PID')
    userid = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='UID')
    accounttype = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='AccType')
    list_display = ('id', 'accounttype', 'userid')
```

---

I changed views.py to

```
class DeleteProfile(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        userprofile = self.get_object(pk)
        userprofile.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

and taking this error from terminal:

```
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Only One Will Live - 3\dysapp\views.py", line 329, in delete
    userprofile = self.get_object(pk)

  File "D:\Only One Will Live - 3\dysapp\views.py", line 324, in get_object
    return UserPorfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
NameError: name 'UserPorfile' is not defined
[27/Jun/2019 11:28:06] "DELETE /user/profile/37/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18477
```

Current Error:

```
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Only One Will Live - 3\dysapp\views.py", line 329, in delete
    userprofile = self.get_object(pk)

  File "D:\Only One Will Live - 3\dysapp\views.py", line 324, in get_object
    return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'objects'
[27/Jun/2019 11:42:16] "DELETE /user/profile/37/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18525
```

Comment: you need to import `UserPorfile` from somewhere, probably from models

Comment: UserPorfile != UserProfile

Comment: Ty fixed it but same error at same lines , "return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)"

Comment: if you fixed that typo then update your code and exception in the post because the exception you posted clearly says that there is typo.

Comment: I think you have defined a class in your views file which is also called UserProfile, which therefore overwrites the model you imported. Call that view something else.

Comment: That is definitly solve the problem. Thank you ! Daniel Roseman and who gives a tip about !

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
......

try:
  # try something
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
  # do something

#### Or use the following
get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=pk)
```

Comment: I changed with  except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:>>except UserProfile.ObjectDoesNotExist: inside view but still have a problem with " AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'ObjectDoesNotExist'"

Comment: Just for the precision the ObjectDoesNotExists is the base class of the DoesNotExist exception, you could look at it deeper here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist

Comment: You don't need to put the UserProfile.ObjectDoesNotExist just add the import and directly catch ObjectDoesNotExist

Comment: use get_object_or_404. from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,

Comment: I try get_object_or_404 but got same problem for that too

Comment: why is this written: from .models import UserProfile in models.py file?

Comment: whats wrong with that ? I import my dysapp>models.py

Comment: You are importing UserProfile and again making the class with same name in that file.

Answer (score 0):

> "I think you have defined a class in your views file which is also
>   called UserProfile, which therefore overwrites the model you imported.
>   Call that view something else. " Daniel Roseman

solved.